# No back button on when starting a new Activity

Tags: android

When starting a new Activity with an Intent, does the bar on the top of an Activity provide a back button automatically? I assumed that's how it works but am not seeing it. If it doesn't appear automatically, what's required to make it appear?

Comment: Have you even tried searching? There are already a lot of answers about this, for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545139/android-back-button-in-the-title-bar

Comment: @Squeazer Thanks for pointing me to that! I did try searching but strangely nothing useful came up. That answered my question completely.

Answer (score 0):

hey if i am right you looking for home up button in action bar

see like that, put this in your new activity

```
getActionBar().setTitle("");
    getActionBar()
            .setBackgroundDrawable(
                    new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(
                            R.color.actionBarBg)));
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

put before setContentView

and it handled by menus

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:

        finish();
        return true;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, the intent which you insert in a startActivity() method, which starts the activity that you want is not related at all with the back arrow on the toolbar() of the activity.

Second, you should see this : [Android - Back button in the title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545139/android-back-button-in-the-title-bar). Maybe, this will work out.

Don't forget to add the meta-data in the manifest! You don't want a "hidden" "NullPointerException".