# How do you remove the back button from a v7 toolbar on Android?

Tags: android, button, android-button

How do you remove the back button from a v7 toolbar on Android?

I highlighted the button that I'm trying to remove in the image below:

[image]

Comment: please provide some information ! just an image ? what do you want to do within this button ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you are using v7 Toolbar you can remove this button with this code :

```
if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
}
```

you can read android [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)) for more information. also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545139/android-back-button-in-the-title-bar) question may help