# Android popup window - back button

Tags: java, android, fragment, popupwindow, android-listfragment

I'm making application where I'm trying to add custom popup window with ability to close it when I click back button. The problem is I don't know how to add this back button. I'm attaching a file which shows what I have now and want I want to achieve.

I'm making application where I'm trying to add custom popup window with ability to close it when I click back button. The problem is I don't know how to add this back button. I'm attaching a file which shows what I have now and want I want to achieve.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfjDr.jpg)

```
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_transaction, null);

            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, 565, 760, true);

            popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

            Toolbar toolbar = popupView.findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
            toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            toolbar.setTitle("New transaction");

            int currentDay = 1;
            int currentMonth = Integer.parseInt(actualChosenMonth.getText().toString().substring(0, 2)) - 1;
            int currentYear = Integer.parseInt(actualChosenMonth.getText().toString().substring(3, 7));
            SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE");
            Date date = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay - 1);
            String currentDayOfWeek = simpledateformat.format(date);
            String currentDateAsString = convertDateToString(currentDay, currentMonth, currentYear, currentDayOfWeek);

            chooseTransactionDate = popupView.findViewById(R.id.chooseTransactionDate);
            chooseTransactionDate.setText(currentDateAsString);
            chooseTransactionDate.setOnClickListener(this);

            chooseTodayTomorrow = popupView.findViewById(R.id.chooseTodayTommorow);
            chooseTodayTomorrow.setOnClickListener(this);

            chooseTransactionType = popupView.findViewById(R.id.chooseTransactionType);
            chooseTransactionType.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            chosenTransactionExpense = popupView.findViewById(R.id.chosenTransactionExpense);
            chosenTransactionIncome = popupView.findViewById(R.id.chosenTransactionIncome);

            transactionCategoryImage = popupView.findViewById(R.id.transactionCategoryImage);

            chooseTransactionCategory = popupView.findViewById(R.id.chooseTransactionCategory);
            ArrayAdapter<String> chooseCategoryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.popup_spinner_layout, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_of_expenses));
            chooseTransactionCategory.setAdapter(chooseCategoryAdapter);
            chooseTransactionCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

            chooseTransactionAmount = popupView.findViewById(R.id.chooseTransactionAmount);
            chooseTransactionAmount.requestFocus();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);

            chooseTransactionName = popupView.findViewById(R.id.chooseTransactionName);

            saveTransactionButton = popupView.findViewById(R.id.saveTransactionButton);
            saveTransactionButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

LAYOUT

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/bacgroundColorPopup"
    tools:context=".TransactionActivity">
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveTransactionButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chooseTransactionName"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:text="@string/save_transaction"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/chooseTransactionAmount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/transactionCategoryImage"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="@color/BrownGrey"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:hint="Amount"
        android:maxLength="5"
        android:textColorHint="@color/BrownGreyBrighter"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_edit_text"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/calculator"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/chooseTransactionName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/chooseTransactionAmount"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="@color/BrownGrey"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:hint="Notes"
        android:textColorHint="@color/BrownGreyBrighter"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_edit_text"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/calculator"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/transactionCategoryImage"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/chooseTransactionType"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dateButtons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/chooseTransactionDate"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.6"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/chooseTodayTommorow"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/yesterday"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/chooseTransactionType"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/dateButtons"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/chosenTransactionExpense"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"
            android:checked="true"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:text="@string/expense"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_color"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/chosenTransactionIncome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:text="@string/income"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_color"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/chooseTransactionCategory"
        android:popupBackground="@color/bacgroundColorPopup"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chooseTransactionType"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar" />
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545139/android-back-button-in-the-title-bar

Comment: I tried to do this but the problem is I'm creating popup window in ListFragment class and it doesn't work there

Comment: How about putting it in your `activity_transaction` layout manually as an image button or sth like that?

Comment: I can do this but I think this is not the most elegant way

Comment: But maybe you're right. I'll try to do this in that way